# Apache POI: change page format for Excel worksheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is there a way to change the page size and layout while creating the Excel document using Apache POI? The default one is A4-vertical, while I need A6-horizontal (landscape).

I don't think that this question requires code sample, the Excel document is created just as described in the manual:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
sheet.getPrintSetup().setLandscape(true);
sheet.getPrintSetup().setPaperSize(HSSFPrintSetup.A5_PAPERSIZE);
```

[HSSFPrinterSetup Javadoc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPrintSetup.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, this functions as expected. I missed this API. the only issue that there is no A6 available in the default formats, but I think I can try to find the closest one from the available.

Comment: Thanks. The same applies to XSSF: e.g. `oSheet.getPrintSetup().setPaperSize(XSSFPrintSetup.A4_PAPERSIZE);` see: [poi.apache.org -> XSSFPrintSetup](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFPrintSetup.html)